# What are the measurements of rank pips as worn in Star Trek The Next Generation?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-insignias

I've been unable to find exact measurements for the pip rank insignia worn in *The Next Generation*. I'm in need of the diameter and height.

Is there also an exact colour for them too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [photos of the various insignia on sale](http://starfleet1701st.yuku.com/reply/11250/t/NEM-era-pips.html#.VHw2aTGsXoE) in the "It's a Wrap" auction website, the following graphic was created by a trek uniform designer called Sparky. Note that those used in Voyager were [slightly thicker](http://www.therpf.com/f45/my-screen-used-star-trek-tng-suit-christies-15008/) by approx 1mm

[image]

As regards the colour, they were originally (season 1 + 2) [made of brass](http://i627.photobucket.com/albums/tt354/sparky042/HllywdPins.jpg) but in later seasons, they were [a metallic brass spray over a grey primer](http://i627.photobucket.com/albums/tt354/sparky042/12adb9553108e0dc1c904d3cd2e6702c.jpg).

Comment: @MichaelN - http://milwaukeemakerspace.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/picard.jpg